# Trying to use.splice to remove duplicates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I am trying to make a function that removes the duplicate array elements from an array and returns the same array with no duplicates. I figured this would work:

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
  nums.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b;});
  let len = nums.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if (nums[i] === nums[i+1]){
      nums.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
  return nums;
};
console.log(removeDuplicates([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]));
```

However the console log at the bottom returns nums as [0,1,1,2,3,4] and not the [0,1,2,3,4] I was expecting. Is there any way to modify the for loop or use splice differently (or maybe some other array method that does not return a new array) to remove that last 1 duplicate?

Comment: A very easy to understand approach: https://gist.github.com/LarsFlieger/ac99da1a122c838daebbc0ce664138f4

Answer (score 2):

You need to decrement the index because the element above it will be shifted into the current index.

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
  nums.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b;});
  let len = nums.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    if (nums[i] === nums[i+1]){
      nums.splice(i,1);
      --i;
    }
  }
  return nums;
};
console.log(removeDuplicates([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]));
```

Alternatively, looping backwards avoids this issue altogether.

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
  nums.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b;});
  let len = nums.length;
  for (let i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (nums[i] === nums[i+1]){
      nums.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
  return nums;
};
console.log(removeDuplicates([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]));
```

A simpler method would be to use a `Set`.

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
  return [...new Set(nums.sort((a,b)=>a-b))];
};
console.log(removeDuplicates([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]));
```